# if isinstance(x, list) appending new values from the list overwrites the previous one

Tags: python

I'm absolutely new to Python trying to automate some of my stuff.

I'm currently trying to find a way to make a dictionary to a table based on columns from the table itself.

```
cursor.execute(query)

columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
rows = [dict(zip(columns, row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]

results = []

for row in rows:
    arg1 = row['arg1']
    arg2 = row['arg2']
    temp = row

    temp['concat'] = (str(arg1) + str(arg2))

    concat = row['concat']

    def map_sth(x):

        return {
            'arg1arg2': ["abcd","efgh"],
            'arg1arg2': "xyz",
                    }[str(x)]  

    mapped = map_sth(concat)

    if isinstance(mapped, list):
        for mapping in mapped:
            temp['new_column'] = mapping
            results.append(temp)
    else:
        temp['new_column'] = mapped
        results.append(temp)

df = pandas.DataFrame(results)
df.to_csv("file.csv",index=False)
```

I debugged the code and it works fine for results with only one item in map_sth

```
    if isinstance(mapped, list):
        for mapping in mapped:
            temp['new_column'] = mapping
            results.append(temp)
    else:
        temp['new_column'] = mapped
        results.append(temp)
```

One it gets into isinstance it gives me correct value for the first loop but once entered in the second loop it overwrites both values with the second phrase from map_sth

Any help would be much appreciated as i'm currently stuck :/

Thanks!

Comment: You meant to say `if isinstance(mapped, list)`? `map_sth` is a function

Comment: Could your `print(rows)` and show us ? So that we could try the code by yourselves. Also show the expected result please

Comment: If you do `temp['new_column'] = mapping` for each value of `mapping` then you're just overwriting the same value over and over and it'll contain the last one you set it to. When you add it to the list it doesn't add a copy, it adds a reference to the dictionary you already have, so each one you add will actually be the same one with the same overwritten values.

Comment: Your `map_sth` is useless, don't create a method just to access a dict, define the dict outside, then  just access it

Comment: @Kemp this is exactly the problem, how could i overcome this?

Comment: Also, don't define `map_sth` every time through the loop. If you need the function, define it once.

Comment: Pandas has a built-in `pandas.read_sql()` function to create a dataframe from a SQL query.

Comment: What is the desired result supposed to be?

Comment: replacing `results.append(temp)` with `results.append(temp.copy())` solved the issue